# is a webview purchase a in app purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase

I want to sell a tshirt for my app. I have a button that goes to a webview ( my website) 
 If people buy from my website in a webview, is that considered an in app purchase?

Answer (score 1):

This is not In App Purchase. In App Purchase does not allow to sell physical product, which you need to ship the physical product to your buyer.
Most of the time will be virtual items, e.g. newspapers, book, game levels, music, those can be delivered by **"DOWNLOADING"**

Answer (score 1):

Apple and Google treat Virtual Goods and Physical goods differently. The good news is that you don't have to pay the 30% toll to use their system. There are many ways to do it either as native code or as a webview. You should also look at pre-made solutions/SDKs like:

- SellInApp
- Zooz
- Paypal

Answer (score 0):

You will need to trap the URL when they click the item in the Webview and proceed with Apple StoreKit to do a In App Purchase with Apple.

Your App will get rejected if you are giving away Digital items from your Webview using your own payment provider.